How would you model energy coming from Car Low-Voltage battery charged by regenerative braking
I want to use the Low Voltage battery in a car to power a device. This battery is recharged by regenerative braking. How do I model the emissions of the energy from the battery used to power this device?
Would we cut off the energy before the regenerative breaking because it's essentially waste energy that would not be used for any other economic purpose? So would the emissions only be the emissions of the production of systems used to enable regenerative braking, storage of Low Voltage energy and delivery of energy to the device (split up by allocation to all the different uses of that energy)?

Welcome @lash This is an awesome question and sounds like a fun project. I'm tempted to take a crack at answering it. You seem to want to play with it and need to know what aspects of the inverter you can control before you decide what you want to control. Do you have any end goals in mind, like making a web interface or a phone app? Also, I don't think you posted it in the best place. It seems like a software and/or electronics question to me.

It depends on what you want to do. There is no standardization (AFAIK), just avoid double counting. In a car? I would just calculate the net consumption (from fuel). Things are more complex if the generated energy is used externally (which should not be the case for cars).
